# Wanderlust: save/restore queued operations accross sessions

Tags: wanderlust

I have scoured the source code of Wanderlust and Elmo, but have not found a mechanism to save/restore queued operations across Emacs sessions -- e.g., delete certain items from the Inbox, move certain items to Spam, etc.  I'd like to do work offline and kill Emacs and then open Emacs at a later date and process the queued operations.  How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanderlust does what you want out of the box:

- operations performed when offline are stored in a queue;
- when starting Wanderlust online, queued operations are executed;
- you can manually switch between online and offline using `M-t`.

Messages to be sent are saved in your `wl-queue-folder`, which must be local (`+queue` is good, `%Queue` isn't); queued actions are saved in the file `.elmo/queue`.  Automatic flushing is controlled by the variable `wl-auto-flush-queue`.

The low-level code is in `elmo-dop.el`, the high-level interface is spread across `wl.el`, `wl-folder.el` and `wl-draft.el`.

Comment: As far as I am aware, operations such as flag setting, deleting, moving, etc, are not stored in a file -- so those operations are lost when closing Emacs.  I haven't yet tracked down all the variables involved, but those variables would need to be saved to a file and restored upon a new session.  Outgoing messages are stored in the queue, but I'm also after the other stuff.

Comment: They are.  Please set Wanderlust offline, delete a message, then quit Wanderlust.  You will see a list of actions in your `.elmo/queue`.

Comment: Perhaps something in my setup is misconfigured then -- I'll do some testing and report back -- thank you for putting me on the right track.

Comment: Update:  Given your hints, I believe I have tracked down my problem.  The `kill-emacs-hook` only contains `wl-save-status`, not `elmo-quit` -- the latter is what populates the `queue` file.  Prior to your explanation, I had never issued the command `wl-exit` -- I had merely killed the buffers or killed Emacs, so `elmo-quit` was never issued.  I'm tempted to add something to the `kill-emacs-hook` in lieu of `wl-save-status` that will also trigger `elmo-quit` and whatever else may be needed.  I'll leave that project, however, for a new day with a cup of coffee in hand -- i.e., it's bedtime . . .

Comment: I've filed a ticket at https://github.com/wanderlust/wanderlust/issues/117

Comment: Thank you very much.  I added `elmo-quit` to an additional `kill-emacs-hook`, but I wasn't quite sure about the best place to also put it so that things are always saved when I kill buffers without typing `wl-exit`.  I placed `elmo-quit` at the tail end of `wl-summary-exec` as I am tentatively planning on using that function a lot while off-line -- e.g., when I delete or move e-mail.  I have a custom setup and have been modifying the Wanderlust and Elmo internals to suit my needs, so it is a little difficult for me to participate in bug fixes because I no longer have a default Emacs -Q setup.

Comment: This should be fixed by https://github.com/wanderlust/wanderlust/commit/3e29a10cddbae350aea5aefd69ba1cded5071a35 .

Comment: Yep, that's where I added the hook addition/removal.  But I also added it at the other location in the comment above so that I don't lose my work when killing the buffers improperly.  The `kill-emacs-hook` is only useful if the Wanderlust buffers are open when killing Emacs, so that's why I added `elmo-quit` at the other location too.

Comment: You should probably discuss that at the github issue.